# Realizar metodo map en javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

estoy tratando de realizar este código con el método map, estoy aprendiendo a trabajar con objetos y me esta costando bastante pillarle la lógica a este método. Yo he conseguido hacerlo con un for in, pero me parece muy sucio y preferiría aprender a hacerlo de manera más correcta.
La función envía tres parámetros, se trata de cambiar el texto de la carta x (primer parámetro) en la lista x (tercer parámetro).
Si alguien me puede ayudar a entender como podria hacerlo con el método map, estaria muy agradecido.

```
 const initial = [
  {
    title : 'Su tarjeta',
    id : 0,
    cards : [
      {
      id : 0,
      text : 'Su tarea'
      },
      {
        id : 1,
        text : 'Su tarea 2'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title : 'Su tarjeta2',
    id : 1,
    cards : [
      {
      id : 0,
      text : 'Su tarea'
      },
      {
        id : 1,
        text : 'Su tarea 2'
      }
    ]
  }
  
];

      function total (idt, newText, listID) {
      for (let i in initial){
        if (initial[i].id ===listID){
          for (let j in initial[i].cards){
            if (initial[i].cards[j].id == idt) {
              initial[i].cards[j].text = newText
              console.log(initial)
            }
            }
          }
        }
      }
        
        total(0, 'Hola que tal',1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido realizarlo, después de muchas intentonas pero me ha quedado bastante claro. He hecho un map de initial y dentro de este, segun la condicion, otro map del array de las cards. Así he accedido al texto que necesitaba. Ha quedado de esta manera. No se muy bien como se haría si hubieran múltiples arrays anidados, supongo que tendría que ir llamando al método map continuamente.

```
function total (idt, newText, listID) {
        return initial.map((list) => {
          if(list.id === listID) {
            return list.cards.map((card) =>{
              if(card.id === idt){
                card.text = newText;
                console.log(initial);
              }
            })
          }
        })
      }
        
        total(0, 'Hola que tal',0);
```